# Is there a simple function can exclude training set from dataset in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question in spliting dataset in python
if I have got a subset of dataset as training, is there some function in python can exclude training set from dataset and get rest of dataset directly?
just like:

```
testing set = numpy.exclude(dataset , trainingset)
```

for example, there are 10 row in dataset, I have took 2,4,7,9 row as training set, so how can I get rest of dataset easily. 
In detail, these my training dataset

```
for i in range(0,5):
  Test_data = dataset[ratio*i:ratio*(i+1),:]
  Train_data = dataset[0:ratio*i&ratio*(i+1):-1,:]
```

My code didn't work because there is no & defination

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. What's special about "training sets" and "datasets"? As far as I can tell the question should just be "How to sample/split a NumPy array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the indices of the training set rows, you can just exclude them to get the indices of the remaining rows:

```
training_rows_ix = [2,4,7,9]
non_training_rows = [i for i in dataset.index if i not in training_rows_ix]
test_set = dataset.loc[non_training_rows]
```

Or using set operations instead of list comprehension:

```
non_training_rows = sorted(set(dataset.index) - set(training_rows_ix))
```

Also for a more robust solution to splitting datasets into test-train look into scikit-learn's [test-train-split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: Could you please see my question again, maybe it more difficult

Comment: I've just answered now.